# Calling Xamarin.Android Interop from Xamarin.UITest

Tags: xamarin, interop, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I've created a method in the first Activity of my app which I have added the Java.Interop.Export tag to, as below.

```
[Export]
public string MyInvokeMethod(string myString)
{
 _webview.LoadUrl("http://www.google.co.uk");
 return "test";
}
```

And I'm trying to call this method in Xamarin.UITest with the below.

```
app.Invoke("MyInvokeMethod","test");
```

However, nothing seems to happen. I looked into the logs of the Android device and it seems as though it is trying to call the method but it gets below error.

"Method not found with correct argument types. Trying to type convert."

Is there a way to get this to work? I have tried with passing an argument, without passing an argument, adding a name for the method in the attribute but nothing has worked.

EDIT

After speaking to one of the Xamarin developers they believe it might be an issue with how MvvmCross handles the Android Activity.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should add 
`[Export("myInvokeMethod:")]` 
on top of your method, instead of only add `[Export]`
Someone using xamarin uitests might find this useful too: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57662/xamarin-forms-uitest